# How to Embed Images in Emails?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I want to send mail with logo and html  template. I added my code here;

```
 <div style="max-width: 31.250em; background-color:#fcf9f2;margin:auto;font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    font-size: 13px;">
    <div class="row">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e0e0e1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table border="0" align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                           class="container590">
                        <td height="50" style="line-height:55px;">
                            <a href=""
                               style=" border-style: none !important; border: 0 !important;"><img
                                    width="0.08em" height="40px" border="0"
                                    style="display:block; width: 170px;"
                                    src="https://www.yemeksepeti.com/assets/images/logo.png?v=1553756111693"
                                    alt="Yemek Sepeti"/></a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</tr>
    <div style="opacity: 0.9;margin-top:4.375em;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 2%">
        <p>  %NameSurname%</p>
    </div>
    <div style="border-style: solid;border-top-width:1px;border-color:#c6c8ca;opacity: 0.9;margin-top:4.375em;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 2%">
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td> %EMAIL%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: initial"> %PASS%</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

</br>
```

When I send the mail, the logo doesn't appear and the img tag says blockingsrc.

I tried to write base64 into src but it didn't.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="data:img/jpg;base64, {{base-64 string}}" />` ?

Comment: Base64 images do not work with most email clients.

Comment: try changing the width of the img tag to a pixel size and see if it makes a difference. You have a width of 0.08em which i doubt Outlooks will read properly. Also width in styles are not read by Outlook.

Comment: @Syfer  I tried but noting change . I changed em to px ,remove width but still I can not see logo

Comment: Which email client is not showing the image?

Comment: @Syfer outlook and gmail

Comment: Support coverage for Base64 images in email: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, maybe you were writing in a wrong way.

`<img src="data:img/jpg;base64, {{base-64 string}}" />`

Comment: @d.k can i know the image type? like what it is jpg or png?

Comment: my image type is png

Comment: Outlook (which uses Word to render HTML images) does not support images embedded this way.

Comment: @d.k then it should be `<img src="data:img/png;base64, {{base-64 string}}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Using Base64 to embed images in html is awesome, note that base64 strings can make your email size big.

Therefore,

1) If you have many images, uploading your images to a server and loading those images from the server can make your email size smaller. (You can get a lot of free services via Google)

2) If there are just a few images in your mail, using base64 strings is definitely an option.

`<img src="data:img/jpg;base64, {{base-64 string}}" />`

Comment: I used  <img src="data:img/jpg;base64, {{base-64 string}}" />  but noting  change

Comment: Base 64 images are definitely not an option. They do not work in most email clients.

Comment: @gwally What can I use ? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Outlook does not render images embedded this way.

Comment: @d.k Host your images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image as an attachment and set its `Content-ID` MIME header (e.g. "xyz"). Your HTML body can then refer to that image using the `src` attribute (e.g. `<img src="cid:xyz">`)